# std::make_shared fails to compile when constructing with parameters from Bitfields

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

Consider the following Smallest Recreate-able Standard Compliant Code

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
struct Foo
{
    int m_field1;
    Foo(int field1):m_field1(field1){};
};
typedef unsigned long DWORD;
typedef unsigned short WORD;
struct BitField {
    struct {
        DWORD   Field1:31;
        DWORD   Field2:1;
    } DUMMY;
};
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo>> bar;
    BitField *p = new BitField();
    //This Line compiles
    auto sp1 = std::shared_ptr<Foo>(new Foo((DWORD)p->DUMMY.Field1));
    //But std::make_shared fails to compile
    auto sp2 = std::make_shared<Foo>((DWORD)p->DUMMY.Field1);
    return 0;
}
```

This code fails to compile in VC11 Update 2 with the following error message

```
1>Source.cpp(23): error C2664: 'std::shared_ptr<_Ty> std::make_shared<Foo,DWORD&>(_V0_t)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'DWORD' to 'unsigned long &'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Foo,
1>              _V0_t=DWORD &
1>          ]
```

I cross checked on [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/WBT8AW#sthash.hLFqKvgK.dpuf), and it compiled successfully. Am I missing something obvious?

A connect Bug was opened https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/804888/with-language-extension-enabled-vc11-an-explicit-cast-is-not-creating-an-rvalue-from-bit-fields

Comment: @Mgetz: VC11 Update 2

Comment: Have you tried using a unary `+` for the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion? `make_shared<Foo>(+(DWORD)p->DUMMY.Field1)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an odd one. The following snippet compiles under the `/Za` (disable language extensions) compiler flag, but not without:

```
struct {
  unsigned field:1;
} dummy = {0};

template<class T>
void foo(T&&){}

int main(){
  foo((unsigned)dummy.field);
}
```

Error without `/Za`:

> error C2664: 'foo' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'unsigned int' to 'unsigned int &'

This is obviously a bug, since the cast to `unsigned` should simply create an rvalue, which should not be deduced as an lvalue-reference and which should not be treated as a bit-field. I have a feeling the extension for "rvalues bind to lvalue-references" plays a role here.

Please file a bug report on Microsoft Connect.

Comment: [From the C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 9.7.3 "If the initializer for a reference
of type const T& is an lvalue that refers to a bit-ﬁeld, the reference is bound to a temporary initialized to
hold the value of the bit-ﬁeld; the reference is not bound to the bit-ﬁeld directly."

Comment: [class.bit]/3 "A non-const reference shall not be bound to a
bit-field (8.5.3)"

Comment: @DyP: Yes, and? The actual argument is not a bit-field anymore.

Comment: @Xeo Yes, with the "workaround" of `unsigned` / a conversion. But that statement *requires* the conversion to something different.

Comment: @Mgetz: Please read the explanation below my answer again. There are no actual bit-fields involved in the function call, the `(unsigned)dummy.field` part creates an rvalue.

Comment: A workaround that works in VS10 w/o using `/Za` is just `+dummy.field` (using integral promotion).

Comment: @DyP: The OP's code also has the cast (albeit to `DWORD`). This is a bug in the compiler when language extensions are enabled, as it deduces the template argument for `foo` as an lvalue-reference, while the actual argument is an rvalue.

Comment: @Xeo Yes that's why I upvoted once I saw your answer. Nevertheless, I thought it was important to point out that a conversion is mandated by the Standard.

Comment: @DyP if you see my comment that's not necessarily the case, the compiler should create a temporary and use that

Comment: @Mgetz An lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is required at least, otherwise the template parameter will be deduced to an lvalue reference.

Comment: Thank you, I filed a connect Bug

Answer (score 2):

The compiler's error message is correct insofar as it really can't create a `DWORD&` from the value you pass in. The bitfield isn't the right size to be a *real* reference to `DWORD`. Whether the compiler is correct to reject your program, I can't say.

It's easy to work around, though. Simply specify the second template parameter when you call `make_shared`:

```
auto sp2 = std::make_shared<Foo, int>(p->DUMMY.Field1);
```

I used `int` because that's the constructor's argument type. You could say `DWORD` instead; any non-reference numeric type would probably be sufficient. You can then also forego the type-casting to `DWORD`. It doesn't do anything more.

Answer (score 2):

Here's more of a comment than an answer. It may shed some light on what's happening.

Example by Xeo

```
struct {
  unsigned field:1;
  unsigned nonfield;
} dummy = {0};

template<class T>
void foo(T&&){}
```

---

Step one: Type deduction.

[class.bit]/1 specifies "The bit-field attribute is not part of the type of the class member." Consequently, type deduction for `foo(dummy.field)` deduces the template parameter to be `unsigned&`.

---

Step two: overload resolution.

Although not strictly necessary here, the Standard has a nice example concerning this in [over.ics.ref]/4

> [Example: a function with an “lvalue reference to `int`” parameter can be a viable candidate even if the corresponding argument is an `int` bit-field. The formation of implicit conversion sequences treats the `int` bit-field as an `int` lvalue and finds an exact match with the parameter. If the function is selected by overload resolution, the call will nonetheless be ill-formed because of the prohibition on binding a non-const lvalue reference to a bit-field (8.5.3). —end example ]

So this function is well-formed and will be selected, but the call will be ill-formed nevertheless.

---

Step three: Workarounds.

The OP's conversion should resolve the problem, `foo( (unsigned)dummy.field )`, as it yields an rvalue which leads to `T` being deduced as `unsigned` and the parameter `unsigned&&` is initialized from a temporary. But it seems that MSVC ignores the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion if source and destination have the same type. Writing `foo( (unsigned)dummy.nonfield )` deduced `T` as `T&` as well (even with a `static_cast`).

The lvalue-to-rvalue conversion required to deduce `T` to `unsigned` rather than `unsigned&` can be enforced by using a unary `+`: `foo( +dummy.field )`

Answer (score 0):

Bit fields can't have references but are sometimes treated sorta like lvalues because they can be assigned to. Bit fields are messy IMO and you should avoid them.

but if you need to convert a bitfield to behaving exactly like an rvalue of the same type you can use a function like below.

```
template<class T>
T frombits(const T& x)  {
    return x;
}
//...
std::make_shared<Foo>(frombits(p->DUMMY.Field1));
```

I'm rather against specifying the template type. When you can, and always when it is intended, let the compiler deduce the type. Template argument deduction can get messy in C++11 but it has been engineered to work very well and work as it should in almost every case. Don't help the compiler and don't think you know better than it; eventually you will loose.